# Use storeButton in a ProductView

Tags: ios, swiftui, storekit, storekit2

I use a StoreKit2 `ProductView` to display a product (there is only one). I want to display a button for restorePurchases via storeButton using
`.storeButton(.visible, for: .restorePurchases, .cancellation)`
, but apparently this button does not work with ProductView. Does anyone know a workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each ProductView equals an `id`. It's used to fetch the in-app purchase information. You have to provide a valid `id` for the ProductView appearance, also check your `bundleID` to match this `id` too. If not, it will show up like a skeleton loading forever.

In case you just want to call `AppStore.sync()`. You can use `StoreView`:

```swift
StoreView(ids: ...)
   .storeButton(.visible, for: .restorePurchases)
```

Comment: Hi, for this code `storeButton(.visible, for: .restorePurchases)`, how do you actually handle restoring the purchase for the user? i.e. I don't see a callback for when the user taps the button.

Comment: There are completions when start/complete purchase. You could try this `StoreView(ids:...).storeButton(.visible, for: .restorePurchases). onInAppPurchaseCompletion` @RubenMartinezJr.